# Does faulTPM defeat the LUKS-based FDE with a passphrase?

Tags: disk-encryption, tpm, bitlocker, luks

The recent `faulTPM` paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2304.14717v1.pdf) deals mostly with Bitlocker and only mentions LUKS to note the differences.

The authors state:

> With a passphrase, however, the same level of security that the passphrase-only protector offers is retained,
> thanks to the additional layer of encryption applied to
> the VMK before it is sealed by the TPM.

But it seems that the `VMK` is Bitlocker-specific.

The abstract closes with:

> Our results
> show that when an fTPM’s internal state is compromised, a
> TPM and PIN strategy for FDE is less secure than TPM-less
> protection with a reasonable passphrase.

The word "PIN" in the Bitlocker context being used interchangeably with passphrase (*"enhanced PIN"*) making this harder to decipher.

AFAIK the LUKS-based FDE, at least by default (as is common i.e. during Ubuntu installation) is using TPM to store the keys.

Does this mean that the FDE/LUKS setup where users provide a passphrase on boot is defeated by `faulTPM`, since the keys are stored in the TPM? Is there a way to use FDE/LUKS in a *"TPM-less"* mode with a passphrase only? If so would this provide sufficient defense against `faulTPM`?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, LUKS volumes don't use a TPM, I can pull my NVMe drive, put it in an enclosure, and log into it with another system so long as I have the password. I'm pretty sure it's just using hash key derivation. I have mine set up to crank on Argon2 for a good 30 seconds after entering my encryption password.